# Can the constructor of a child class update the values of variables in the parent class

Tags: java, constructor, polymorphism, overriding

[question problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vHBU.jpg)

In the question above var 1 is of type A but is calling the constructor of class B. So will passing the parameter 4 to the constructor update the "value" variable to 4 or will it remain 3.

I was expecting the answer of the final question to be 11 but it was actually 10.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try actually running the code? Did you try using a debugger, in order to see what happens step by step? Also, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: please don't post code as pictures

Comment: You are still calling the constructor for class `B` because you're creating an object of type `B` (`new B(...)`). It doesn't matter that you've stored a reference to that object of type `B` in a variable of type `A`. The object's type is still `B`.

Comment: A subclass constructor can update the fields of the superclass. In your specific case however the class `B` has two fields named `value`: the one from the class `B` itself and an inherited and hidden one from the class `A`. Without special constructs within the class `B` you always access the class `B`s field. However when referencing a `B` object through a class `A` reference you access class `A`s field.

Answer (score -2):

No. If the variable is calling a constructor from a different class, it will not update anything in the A class at all even though the two classes use a constructor with the same name. The two constructors go to two different locations in memory.

Comment: "If the variable is calling a constructor" That doesn't make sense. At all.

Comment: Oops, I meant method.